# Node.js MVC framework

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js

I would like to use Node.js to develop a website. I've seen a lot of frameworks here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#web-frameworks-micro but do not know which one is the most accepted by the community (let's say: the most popular). Did anyone tried any of these frameworks and/or used it in production and what is your experience? Thanks.

Comment: Why is this not community wiki?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Express.js` seems to very popular to use as a general framework. Combined with `socketio.js` and `underscore.js` these are very popular libraries but they are not MVC.

For MVC I've only used `backbone.js` / `spine.js` and can't give any recommendation for the others. I don't think there is a framework with a dominating popularity going yet because node.js doesn't have much use in production.

There are statistics for popular downloads with `npm` somewhere. See if you can find them.

Comment: I'm quite sure you can use Express.js to build MVC style webapps. You have routes, you have a viewengine. Controllers and Models are just objects. Everything is there, you're just missing the conventions and tools of .NET MVC or Rails.

Comment: @OscarKilhed yes you can but the MVC code you write from scratch is going to be tightly coupled to that website and can't be re-used on different websites. It's best to use express in combination with something like backbone to have Models, Views & Collections in a standard website agnostic API.

Comment: @Raynos You mean http://www.nodecloud.org/ where website are ranked using their Alexa score?

Answer (score 15):

Try <strike>[RailwayJS](http://railwayjs.com/).</strike> [CompoundJS](http://compoundjs.com/)

RailwayJS seems to have been killed and replaced with CompoundJS.

There's a [guide](https://github.com/1602/compound/blob/master/docs/migration-guide.md) for anyone that started with Railway and wants to migrate to Compound.

Comment: Anyone having experience with this one and how it compares with http://locomotivejs.org/ ?

Answer (score 15):

Another great MVC framework that is up and coming is Sails.JS.  It is inspired by ruby on rails and has features such as socket support, Restful API and more.

http://www.sailsjs.com/

Comment: I've been testing nodejs frameworks for like 30 days now ;). Yeah... SailsJS is my pick at the moment. The community is rising every week which is positive. Btw... use the latest 0.10.x RC version but be prepared that the documentation is still vague (it was the same with Ruby on Rails in its early stage). Also... I saw that google was using SailsJS in one of their big events which can't be bad ;).

Comment: It's worth noting that SailsJS released their official [v1.0.0 26 days ago](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/releases/tag/v1.0.0), so it clearly is still under active development. I have however seen [very bad performance ratings from TechEmpower](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r15&hw=ph&test=fortune&l=hra0an). SailsJS without a database runs ~100x slower than Express with MySQL.

Answer (score 14):

I just released [Locomotive](http://locomotivejs.org/), which is an MVC framework inspired by Ruby on Rails.

Express is phenomenal, especially for smaller apps.  Recognizing that, Locomotive is built completely on top of Express (similar to how Express builds on top of Connect).  Locomotive essentially adds a controller layer along with a router that can declare resourceful routes and generates routing helper functions.  Internally, everything is powered by Express, which means the view layer remains the same and all middleware can be reused.

One of the bigger hurdles when learning Node is figuring out how to best structure a web application.  Locomotive attempts to solve that problem, using conventions from Ruby on Rails, while retaining the full power of Express and Node.

Comment: For me personally, that is exactly the level of abstraction that I want!  +1 for locomotive

Answer (score 4):

There is [matador](http://medium.github.io/matador/). It is MVC and it consists of many different existing components, such as [Klass](https://github.com/ded/klass) for inheritance model, express, hogan.js, and valentine. Backbone.js is pretty much used for client side. For node, i think there's probably only matador that I know.

I'd suggest you against using it if you're to use matador for production or replace your existing MVC platform (or at least have a bottleneck/good reason to use it) since it's pretty new, and your productivity also depends on the javascript resources you have. We ourselves use node.js very extensively (our node.js deployment serves close to +4 Million users to date) and we have a significant number of javascript specialists here..so we experiment a lot and probably look into using matador soon. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Geddy was the original MVC framework for Nodejs, check out http://geddyjs.org if you're interested.

Comment: +1. Compare the activity on Github between Geddy and others. Clearly Geddy has several long-term contributors, not just one-time bug fixers: https://github.com/mde/geddy/contributors

Answer (score 2):

Just came across a new one called [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/) which looks like it has a lot of promise. Its main benefit seems to be that it cuts down on a lot of the "glue code" (as they put it) that we often write when trying to use rails and backbone, or django and backbone together. The documentation seems pretty decent for a node framework as well.

Answer (score 1):

Monorail.js - Ultra lightweight MVC Framework for Node.js
https://github.com/runexec/Monorail.js

Comment: On the site it is mentioned that the main developer doesn't plan on maintaining it, which may mean that this framework is far from the most popular, therefore it doesn't exactly fit as an answer to this question.

Comment: Very good comment by @PelletenCate ! The last update to Monorail.js   was done on Sep 19, 2012

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more frameworks which you could check:

ThinkJS  https://thinkjs.org/  the first Node.js MVC framework that can use full ES6/7 features to develop Node.js application.

Feathers  http://feathersjs.com/ a minimalist real-time framework.

Meteor https://www.meteor.com/

Keystone.js http://keystonejs.com/  built on Express and MongoDB (MIT license).

seneca.js http://senecajs.org/  Everything external to a business logic - such as databases, caches and third-party integrations - is hidden behind microservices.

Catberry http://catberry.org/ was developed to help create apps that use the same codebase on both the server and client environments to render what the client would see as a "Single Page Application".

Nuke.js http://nukejs.com/#/ Fast framework. The stack contains primus, express, mithril, mongodb and redis

Hapi.js http://hapijs.com/  rich web application server framework for Node.js.

total.js  https://www.totaljs.com/  The framework contains full web server, view engine, SMTP mail sender, localization, image processing, websockets, isomorphic code and a lot of utilities