# State of the art in MVC frameworks for node.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, node.js

I'd very much like to have some idea of the state of the art of MVC frameworks for **node.js**. Specifically, current commercial practice of the art, not research, with frameworks for front-end web apps. As a PHP programmer might choose Yii Framework—what are the options for node.js programmers and what are the pros and cons for the main contenders?

Comment: In addition to expressjs, i've heard of geddy. A glance at github suggests its project is less active than expressjs. Anyone care to comment—in an answer?

Comment: express is the best, most active developed framework. TJ commits almost every day to express. In my opinion learnboost creates very good libraries. Take for example express and socket.io.

Comment: Alfred, it would be worth mentioning lernboost and socket.io in your answer (or another answer?). What other libs should be noted here? TJ/Visionmedia's jade looks interesting. Speaking generally, it seems we're in the early days of SSJS so listing the best of the various bits and pieces currently available might be the best answer my question is entitled to.

Comment: I found http://nodebeginner.org/ to be a great read. It fleshes out the basics of a framework and might be a good place to start if you end up rolling your own. But I'm happy with Express.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js MVC framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248582/node-js-mvc-framework)

Comment: @Tauren: Put that in an answer. Node Beginner deserves the extra visibility.

Comment: Haha fsb, you came to the same conclusion as I did after looking at all node.js web frameworks, because you excepted my answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**

Searched http://search.npmjs.org and https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules for **MVC frameworks** and noted last commit/followers. As you can see `express` is the most popular and with a reason if you ask me.

```
https://github.com/visionmedia/express
last commit: about an hour ago
followers: 3115

https://github.com/tuxychandru/grasshopper
last commit: about 23 hours ago
followers: 130

https://github.com/mde/geddy
last commit: June 18, 2011
followers: 491

https://github.com/DracoBlue/spludo
last commit: 47
followers: 

https://github.com/chetan51/ni
last commit: May 07, 2011
followers: 55

https://github.com/1602/express-on-railway
last commit: 5 days ago
followers: 153

https://github.com/fakewaffle/piejs
last commit: June 22, 2011
followers: 9

https://github.com/DracoBlue/spludo
last commit: 23 hours ago
followers: 47

https://github.com/xenophy/NextJS
last commit: February 15, 2011
followers: 18
```

---

The best/only(I think so..) option is http://expressjs.com/. This is the most popular "High performance, high class web development for Node.js". I also advice you to have a look at Learnboost's Jade's "high performance template engine"(view). Also socket.io is very interesting if you "aim to make realtime apps possible in every browser and mobile device, blurring the differences between the different transport mechanisms. It's care-free realtime 100% in JavaScript."

Comment: Thanks for your input, Alfred. I'll leave it unaccepted for a while longer in the hope that some others might chime in.

Comment: @fsb Haha okay. The best answer should be accepted anyway so what at least a couple of days I guess. But I am going to tell you that express is the best(if you ask me). See my updated answer for example, which I try to compare a lot of (MVC) frameworks.

Comment: I've also found express to be the best option, and therefore really the **only** option.  The only other option is well creating your own, if your just wanting to understand the internals of everything.

Comment: it's worth mentioning backbone. Express only really does routing, middleware and view engines. It doesn't do anything for application logic.

Comment: @Raynos backbone is also very popular as is underscore.

Answer (score 3):

We've been using our MVC framework, [Sails](http://sailsjs.com), in a production environment for several of our clients since March.  It's built on Express, Socket.io, and Sequelize.  The main distinction is that it routes realtime Socket.io requests the same way as standard HTTP requests: using Express routes.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

As requested, I'm putting my comment in an answer.

I found http://nodebeginner.org to be a great read. It fleshes out the basics of a framework and might be a good place to start if you end up rolling your own.

But I'm happy with Express and wouldn't want to write it myself.

I also use Backbone.js for all of my client-side MVC and routing.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a search on twitter for nodejs and mvc - and it pointed to something called matador - https://github.com/Obvious/matador. I haven't used it, but would like to see a comparison before I pick one...

Answer (score 0):

This hand Hand-picked registry of Node.js frameworks may be useful:

http://nodeframework.com/index.html